# Angular console error NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using following versions

"@angular/cdk": "^12.2.6",
"@angular/material": "^12.2.6"

I am getting this issue on console

```
  Ecore.js:6479 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(InnerModule)[MatCommonModule -> HighContrastModeDetector -> HighContrastModeDetector -> HighContrastModeDetector]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for HighContrastModeDetector!
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(InnerModule)[MatCommonModule -> HighContrastModeDetector -> HighContrastModeDetector -> HighContrastModeDetector]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for HighContrastModeDetector!
```

Package.Json

```
{
  "name": "docu-sign-web",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.6",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^12.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^6.4.1",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^10.1.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "signature_pad": "^3.0.0-beta.4",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "ultimate-text-to-image": "^1.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.6",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show the contents of `package.json` file. This error is mostly due to incompatible Angular and Angular Material versions.

Comment: Package.Json added

Comment: Did you add HighContrastModeDetector to the providers of your module (example: AppModule)

Comment: @FatihErsoy not added. Kindly let me know the code or reference link

Comment: @ArunKrishnan please check this: https://angular.io/guide/providers

Comment: I have added  providers: [ HighContrastModeDetector ] but still issue is there